# read video file from mongodb with pymongo

Tags: pymongo, gridfs

I have a large video file stored in MongoDB gridFS.
I would like to read it and write it on my disk.
I can find the file in the database with:

```
 file = grid_fs.find_one({"filename":'file_in_database.cin'})
```

I get back a grid out object **gridfs.grid_file.GridOut at 0xa7b7be0**

I try to write the file on my disk with:

```
 with open('file_from_database.cin', 'w') as f:
      f.write(file.read())
```

I get the file written but the size of the one download from the database is slightly different from the original size of the file:

```
05/15/2015  09:09 AM        65,585,808 file_from_database.cin
08/01/2007  01:08 PM        65,585,800 Original_file.cin
```

I checked the file in the database and the md5 field is the same as the original so the problem must be during the download or writing.

I'm using win7 64 and anaconda64  dirstribution for python 2.7

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I tried the same code with a jpeg image and I get the same problem, the image is stored well in the database but when I get it and write it to the disk the size is slightly different and I cannot read it.

```
03/20/2015  02:36 PM         5,422,339 original_image.JPG
05/15/2015  02:44 PM         5,438,750 image_from_database.JPG
```

Am I doing some simple mistake reading the gridout and writing to the disk?

interesttingly if I open the image with:

```
PIL.Image.open(file)
```

I can get the image fine. Any Idea?

Comment: what is the `length` of `file` when you get it from `GridFS`?

Comment: the one I get back from the mongodb is 65,585,808 while the original one is 65,585,800, just 8 bytes more but enough to make it non readable.

Comment: I did not get your question at first, I did file.length now and I get 65585800 so the error must be in the reading and writing.

Comment: should you write it as 'wb' . since it is binary